# IBM Bluemix Liberty for Java public accessible directory

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I develop a Java Web Application in IBM Bluemix using the Liberty for Java runtime. Within my application I create csv files, which I'd like to offer to my users as a download.

Unfortunately, I was not able to figure out where I have to write these files to. The url should be like http://myapp.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/test.csv or maybe http://myapp.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/download/test.csv

Do I have to specify a route in my server.xml?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that deploying an application in the Cloud (specifically to a Cloud Foundry-based platform) requires some considerations regarding the local file system:

- **Local file system storage is short-lived**. When an application instance crashes or stops, the resources assigned to that instance are reclaimed by the platform including any local disk changes made since the app started. When the instance is restarted, the application will start with a new disk image. Although your application can write local files while it is running, the files will disappear after the application restarts.
- **Instances of the same application do not share a local file system**. Each application instance runs in its own isolated container. Thus if your application needs the data in the files to persist across application restarts, or the data needs to be shared across all running instances of the application, **the local file system should not be used**.

If you want more information on this topic please take a look at [Considerations for Designing and Running an Application in the Cloud](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/prepare-to-deploy.html).

I suggest you to take a look at the [Object Storage](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/object-storage) service on Bluemix, that allows to store your data and retrieve it using an API.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I did not know about this facts. But these restrictions won't bother me, because the csv files are only temporarily stored for download and can be deleted afterwards. Furthermore I only need to invoke one app instance. That's why also the second point is no problem. So could you nevertheless tell me, where to store my files in the local file system and how to make it accessible via an url?

Comment: I'd use the Object Storage, but if you want to do that using the filesystem you could simply save the file in a path of your choice and then map the URL  you need to a servlet method that goes in the same path, retrieves the file and sends it in the response.

Comment: But with this solution I have to open each downloaded file on my server, read its lines and write them into my response. Is there no solution by simply mapping a url to a download directory?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not download the file right away? Instead of writing the data to a `FileWriter` or `FileOutputStream`, write the data to a `PrintWriter` or `OutputStream` obtained from the `HttpServletResponse`.

For example:

```
response.setContentType("text/csv");
OutputStream outputStream=response.getOutputStream();
writeCsvData(outputStream);
```

or

```
response.setContentType("text/csv");
PrintWriter writer=response.getWriter();
writeCsvData(writer);
```

Comment: Thanks or your answer! Unluckily, it could be more than one csv file and after creation of them, the user shall decide if and which files he want's to download. Its the functional requirement... But as I already commented in the other answer the csv files are only temporarily stored for download and can be deleted afterwards. So this would be no problem... But I still need to make the accessible via a url.

Comment: This is where ZipOutputStream is useful. The users select the files, you generate them to a zip output stream, and the user gets a zip file with all of the csv file. Again, no need to store anything on disk.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. The workflow is as it follows: The user klicks a button, then I generate the csv data in my server. After that, the user can tick the available csv files and klick a download button. Thats why I have to store the files..

Answer (score 0):

Granted that you are fully aware of the issues related to the [ephemeral file system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37444532/2747442) in Cloud Foundry, you should be able to get the real path of your application on disk via `ServetContext.getRealPath('/')` call. Now, assuming you deployed a simple web application, you can write files to that location and have them accessible via `http://<appName>.mybluemix.net/<file>`. This should also work if you are using a non-root context path or want to put files in a sub-directory (as long as that sub-directory is not `WEB-INF` or `META-INF`).

Comment: Thanks for your hint! But I get the error: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getRealPath(String) from the type ServletContext

Comment: OK, getServletContext().getRealPath("/") worked for me. I get /home/vcap/app/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/apps/myapp.war as realPath. But if I write the csv to this location, I could not access it as you wrote before...